# IntelliJ Rest Client: Use client SSL certificate with rest call

Tags: rest, ssl, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use IntelliJ Ultimate's built-in [REST Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rest-client-tool-window.html#d1579381e402) to test some web services over SSL. However, because the REST services are looking for a client certificate, I'm getting the following error when I try to hit the endpoint:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I've scoured the documentation and haven't found a way to attach a certificate (.p12 file, in my case) to the call. It would be the same file I've uploaded into my browser to facilitate the SSL calls. Maybe there's a different way to do this that I'm not aware of? I'm not an expert in this area.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/server-certificates.html

Comment: Those are server certificates, not the client certificates. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Comment: No, I never did. Still a big pain to have to use a Firefox plugin like HttpRequester to test out my endpoints.

Comment: Few years later. Is this included in anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't seem to be supporting this yet.
Still using sublime with HttpRequester plugin, it supports all cases
https://github.com/braindamageinc/SublimeHttpRequester